# Is the order of cokernel of trace map of elliptic curve a power of 2?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic extension of a number field.
Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve.

There is a trace map $E(L)\to E(K)$ given by $P\to P+P^{\sigma}$, where $\sigma$ is a generator of $Gal(L/K)$.

Why is $\#coker(trace)$ always a power of $2$ ?

My try: There is a exact sequence $0\to E_D(\Bbb{Q})\to E(K)\to E(\Bbb{Q})\to coker(trace)\to 0$.

By Model-weil theorem and the fact $rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=rank(E/\Bbb{Q})+rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$,
we can put $ E_D(\Bbb{Q})\cong \Bbb{Z}^{r'}×T'', E(K)\cong \Bbb{Z}^{r+r'}×T', \Bbb{Z}^r×T$.

Thus $\#coker(trace)={\#T''}\#T/{\#T'}$.

But I have doubts about whether ’${\#T''}\#T/{\#T'}$ is a power of 2’ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were overthinking this.

By Mordell-Weil we know that $E(K)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. Because $P^{\sigma}=P$ for all $P\in E(K)$, it follows that $[2]E(K)$ is contained in the image of the trace $T:E(L)\to E(K)$.

By virtue of $E(K)$ being finitely generated, already $E(K)/[2]E(K)$ is a finite elementary abelian $2$-group. Consequently, the same holds for its quotient group $E(K)/T(E(L))$. After all, we are moding out a subgroup containing $[2]E(K)$.

Comment: Promoting my comment to an answer lest this question get stuck in the limbo.

Comment: I'm wondering why $coker(trace)$ does not depend on the information of $L$. Can we grasp the reason why $coker(trace)$ is not influenced by $L$ intuitively ?

Comment: Sorry, $coker(trace)$ depends on $L$, but it is bounded by the group only influenced by $K$. I'm a bit wondering why $coker(trace)$ is bounded by a group with no information of $L$.

Comment: @Pont The power of Mordell-Weil makes the cokernel finite. Otherwise it is somewhat analogous to the norm map $N:L^*\to K^*, z\mapsto z \sigma(z)$. There, similarly, all the squares of elements of $K$ are in the image, and the quotient $K^*/N(L^*)$ is an interesting quotient group of $K^*/(K^*)^2$. The difference coming from how various primes of $K$ behave in the extension (split/inert/ramify). I'm not an expert on such arithmetic properties of elliptic curves, but I suspect the reasons for studying $E(K)/T(E(L))$ are similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your intriguing explanation. I came to like trace map than before.Could I ask just one more thing?If we define $T': E(L)\to E(L), P\mapsto P+P^{\sigma}$,  is $image(T)=image(T')$ ? I think both are $\{P+P^{\sigma}\mid P\in E(K)\}$, thus the same, but if so, the cokernel is different.Like this, I am confused by the fact that there are two styles of defining 'trace'.